# Poor images in DataGridView

Tags: image, datagridview, zooming

I've written a little application to do something similar to outlook, looking at .msg files on the hard drive.
I am using a dataGridView to show the messages in a folder, and I want to display a little icon in the left hand column to indicate a message file (or a different icon for calendar/contact/etc).
I have copied a little mail item image and saved as a gif.
But when I load the image into the datagridview it looks bad - it's more or less correct but poor quality.  See image - at the top left just above my application is the image file as displayed by IE (or any other editor) and below is my application where the same image file displays poorly.
I have tried zoom/stretch/normal but they all look about the same.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Oh- just realised I'm not alowed to post images. Well basically the bad version looks like the good version but scaled up a bit and not particularly well - fuzzy, some loss of colour fidelity etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out - very silly.
The problem was not with DataGridView but with the ImageList I was using to import the images.
Phil